# java natative hook mouse event detecting issue

Tags: java

im still pretty new to Java but im having this issue when trying to detect if my mouse is down. I saw a another post about this issue, but the answer didn't seem to work for me.
Here's the code, simply trying to make it only click when the mouse is down.

```
    @Override
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {
    if (nativeMouseEvent.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1 && BUTTON1 == 1) {
        Robot robot;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
            robot.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.delay(50);
            robot.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            
        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jwinkey](https://github.com/lukasl-dev/jwinkey)
It looks something like this and works without any Swing or FX Component open or in focus:

```java
var observable = KeyStateObservable.of(VirtualKey.VK_LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON);
observable.subscribe((event) -> {
    System.out.println(event.getVirtualKeyCode());
});
```

But you need to add  io.reactivex.rxjava3 for `Obserable`